# How to fix a Static Library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, linker-errors

I'm trying to learn how to debug static libraries and I am trying to fix JsonCpp in particular.

What project settings can I use to see exactly what's being linked in the output window in Visual Studio?

==================================================================================

Here are the errors that I am getting:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)    msvcprtd.lib

Error   2   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) msvcprtd.lib

Error   3   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj)    msvcprtd.lib

Error   4   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Core.obj msvcprtd.lib

Error   5   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in Core.obj   msvcprtd.lib

Error   6   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in Core.obj msvcprtd.lib

Error   7   error LNK2005: "public: char const * __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEPBDXZ) already defined in Core.obj    msvcprtd.lib

Error   8   error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QBEXXZ) already defined in Core.obj msvcprtd.lib

Error   9   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Core.obj  msvcprtd.lib

Error   10  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Core.obj   msvcprtd.lib

Error   11  error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const *)" (??4?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV01@PBD@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj)  msvcprtd.lib

Error   12  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(unsigned int,char)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ID@Z) already defined in Serialization.obj  msvcprtd.lib

Error   13  error LNK2005: "public: unsigned int __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::size(void)const " (?size@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEIXZ) already defined in Core.obj    msvcprtd.lib

Error   14  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in Serialization.obj    msvcprtd.lib

Error   15  error LNK2005: "public: static bool __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eq_int_type(int const &,int const &)" (?eq_int_type@?$char_traits@D@std@@SA_NABH0@Z) already defined in Serialization.obj   msvcprtd.lib

Error   16  error LNK2005: "public: static int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eof(void)" (?eof@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAHXZ) already defined in Serialization.obj    msvcprtd.lib

Error   17  error LNK2005: "public: static unsigned int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::length(char const *)" (?length@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAIPBD@Z) already defined in Core.obj   msvcprtd.lib

Error   18  error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)    MSVCRTD.lib

Error   19  error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)    MSVCRTD.lib

Error   20  error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)    MSVCRTD.lib

Error   21  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(void)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) MSVCRTD.lib

Error   22  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   MSVCRTD.lib

Error   23  error LNK2005: _strchr already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strchr.obj)   MSVCRTD.lib

Error   24  error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)   MSVCRTD.lib

Error   25  error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj)  
MSVCRTD.lib

Error   26  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)    MSVCRTD.lib

Error   27  error LNK2005: _memmove_s already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove_s.obj) MSVCRTD.lib

Error   28  error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj) MSVCRTD.lib

Error   29  error LNK2005: _sprintf_s already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj)   MSVCRTD.lib

Error   30  error LNK2005: _strpbrk already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strpbrk.obj) MSVCRTD.lib

Error   31  error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)  MSVCRTD.lib

Error   32  error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)    MSVCRTD.lib

Warning 33  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library   Afterfuture Game Engine

Error   34  fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found C:\Users\Blake\Desktop\Afterfuture\Afterfuture Game Engine\Debug\Afterfuture Game Engine.exe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are linking together two different versions of the same library. If a library is statically-linked to the debug, single-threaded version of the standard C-library, an application using that library cannot dynamically-link to the release, multi-threaded version of the same runtime library.

Otherwise, you wind up with, for example, two different memory allocators and mayhem if memory is allocated from one but returned to the other. So even if the linker allowed you to do this, the application couldn't safely interoperate with the library anyway -- so what would be the point?

Suppose the library is already statically linked to the multithreaded version of the standard C library and the application dynamically links to the single threaded version. What happens if the library calls `delete` on an object that was allocated by the application and the library's allocator has to free an object despite never having allocated one?!

There is simply no way to make this work reliably. Either statically-link everything to the exact same static library or dynamically-link everything. (This is basically the reason dynamic-linking is preferred. Otherwise, you have to link *all* libraries and the application at the same time or be *very* careful.) Consider yourself lucky the symbols collided and you got a warning.

Comment: Are you asking what would be the point of fixing this static library?  I am able to fix the source.

Comment: Then just compile it to use the same standard C library your project uses and link to it the same way. If your project dynamically-links to the multi-threaded release standard C library, recompile the library to link that same way. (See the second sentence of my last paragraph.)

Comment: I don't really see how that answers my question, I appreciate your consideration but I am just looking for methods of debugging the source that was used to build the static library.

I have two projects, one project is my main executable and the other is my static library (which is being used by my executable project).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the source. The problem is linking. You need to rebuild the static library, linking it to the same version of the C standard library as you're linking your project (multithreaded, DLL). There's nothing to debug. You just need to relink that library so it's using the same C library your application is.

Comment: @Aux Give us much more detail. What run-time library did you link the library against? And static or dynamic? What run-time library do you link the application against? And static or dynamic?

Comment: I believe the static library is being linked against LIBCMTD.lib.

Comment: Is everything compiled with the same version of VC?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4966/discussion-between-aux-and-david-schwartz)

Comment: I have checked the library that is being used during code generation and they are both linking to LIBCMTD.lib.